# Does getting "Unsung Hero" gold badge mean that you post low quality answers?

Tags: discussion, badges

Today I got the [Unsung Hero](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero) badge. First, I thought: "Progress! Second gold badge!". Then I understood that it is given for 10 zero voted accepted answers.

Should one avoid getting this badge? Is it shameful?

Comment: Perusing some of your zero score accepted answers they probably need a lot more detail and explanation to get upvotes. I don't know if people in the JavaScript tag are less likely to upvote anyway though.

Comment: Look up the definition of "unsung hero".

Comment: It's not shameful. But anyway badges are also not so important.

Comment: *"Does getting “Unsung Hero” gold badge means that you post low quality answers?"* Answer: **No** (hence the down-vote). I have quite a few and I put it down to the fact that the tag I answer in most isn't that popular ([tag:asp-classic]) or has a lot of new members who don't understand accepting answers and the whole scoring mechanic. That doesn't make my answers in anyway lacking.

Comment: Side question: can you lose this badge if your ratios change? I'm guessing not...

Comment: @Duncan No. And they forgot to add "accepted" in description, as I understood: "Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total **accepted**". Now, of all accepted (32 - not al lot of course), I have 9 zero voted - after I got this badge 2 answers were already up voted, 'cause I had 11 zero voted accepted.

Comment: @nicael Looks like I'm not the only confused one! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57244/unsung-hero-requirement. And yes, you are quite right on the description.

Comment: Why do you keep making your title less and less descriptive? What's wrong with the original title? This is not the first time I've seen you make a series of questionable edits on your posts...

Comment: @BoltClock You'll kill me some day. First title was better? This will definitely receive more attention.

Comment: The meaning of of an unsung hero is that a person's good deeds or abilities have gone unrecognized or haven't received adequate praise

Comment: "One who does great deeds but receives little or no recognition for them." - Unsung Hero

Comment: One thing I believe I am talented in is understanding a questioner who doesn't know how to express themselves in a question, and ends up asking for the wrong thing.  So I sometimes see a situation where nobody has understood what the questioner wanted, but lots of people have posted elaborate, clever answers that win lots of upvotes.  Meanwhile, I post an answer which is what the OP wanted, but which doesn't win the popularity contest.  Tell me - is this a good talent for me to have, or a bad one?

Comment: @DavidWallace Definetly good.

Comment: It's really difficult to get those green check marks and at the same time a score of 0 on a highly-trafficked question no matter what quality you post at.  If your quality is low, then you're less likely to get the check.  if the quality is high, than you get a score of more than 0

Answer (score 152, accepted):

If you spend your time answering questions in low traffic tags from 1-rep users
(who can't upvote) it is entirely possible to have good answers that do not get
any upvotes. That is the purpose of the badge - to offer some reward for users
who spend a lot of time in low traffic tags.

However, if you spend a lot of time in high traffic tags and you don't get a lot
of up votes, then maybe you do need to consider how you answer questions.

In the end, there is nothing specifically negative about the badge. It can be a
badge of honor, but it might be worth looking through your answers to see why
you aren't getting up votes.

- Are you active in tags where views from users with accounts are low, making
  votes hard to come by.
- Is the community of your preferred tags very stingy with votes?
- Do you spend virtually all your time answering basic questions from low rep
  users?

Once you figure that out, you can decide if you want to address it by trying
improve your old answers or improve your future answers.

Comment: Incidently  I also got my first gold badge 'Unsung Hero' today, When I verify, most of question asked by guys having higher reputation, still they do not upvote my asnwers :).

Comment: "answering basic questions from low rep users" actually this is a very good strategy to gather upvotes on StackOverflow, they will get a lot of views in the first few minutes, because they are easy to answer. But you have to be "first!!11!".

Comment: @Chris - When doing this please make sure it is a valid/good quality question first.

Comment: I posted a question about a "controversial" badge a while ago. I removed it because the question was heavily downvoted. I also have the "Unsung Hero" badge. I give many correct, but unpopular answers. People post a "stupid" question; I answer *"it's not possible and here's why."* The question gets accepted (because i'm right), but nobody likes it, so nobody upvotes it (on the contrary: sometimes I'm even downvoted). In the end, I'm starting to be reluctant to "bring the bad news", especially after the comments I got on my "controversial" badge question.

Comment: I believe certain communities lack the courtesy of up-voting(for eg: coffee machine shuts down for all PHP developers around the world). May be there should a most 'non-voted' badge for communities as well. A bit negative but it would give encouraging results

Comment: There's no fundamental difference between answering questions in a low traffic tag and answering questions in a high traffic tag with answers that only help a limited number of people.  In either case, you're only helping a limited number of people.

Comment: @Chris It's only a good strategy for gaining rep if the questions from low rep users are in tags that get a lot of traffic.  If it's a low-traffic tag, it can remain as a low-vote answer for a **long** time.

Answer (score 42):

I thought to comment, but need 50+ reputation to do it. But I couldn't resist sharing a link from [Rediff.com](http://qna.rediff.com/questions-and-answers/what-is-the-meaning-of-unsung-hero/7962418/answers) esp. when I didn't know much about Unsung Hero.

> An Unsung hero is one who executes and implements an action but
>   doesn't get due credit or acknowledgment for his actions. An unsung
>   hero is one who acts like a messiah or a manna from heaven who has
>   talent but doesn't get a platform to show case it. He can either be a
>   simple rural boy or an aspiring actor with a penchant for acting. Most
>   of the Unsung heroes are philanthropists and Samaritans who do a lot
>   of benevolent deeds.

Comment: Valid answer. Why to comment?

Comment: It was just a definition of `Unsung Hero`. Didn't knew whether SO would entertain it :).

Comment: One of the comments on that page cracked me up

Comment: "The HERO who doesnt sings songs"

Comment: Now you've got enough rep to comment :)

Comment: Notice, that you got it (reputation) not because of this answer, but because of your questions on the main site. Questions and answers there (on Meta Stack Overflow) don't affect your reputation - it is the same as on the main site (Stack Overflow).

Answer (score 36):

The "unsung hero" badge means that you have provided a number of answers that have helped the newbie poster of the question but have not helped other people, whether because the question is in an area that few people are interested in, or because the question is very specific to the original poster's situation.  You are a hero because you are helping people; you are unsung because people other than those you helped do not recognize your heroism.

There is plenty of room on Stack Overflow for answers that help only the asker of the question.  If someone has spent days wrestling with a bug and can't find it, posting the relevant code here in the hopes that someone with a fresh set of eyes can find it is perfectly legitimate.  Similarly with someone posting a question on such an obscure topic that no one else is ever likely to be in the same situation.  No one should feel obligated to answer such questions, but no one should feel bad about answering them either.

Personally, "Unsung Hero" is one of the badges I respect the most.  It means the person is interested in actually helping people, even if the reputation rewards are minimal.

Comment: I just got the tenacious silver badge, which is the lesser version of unsung hero. I answer in low volume tags, and your answer makes me feel good about it.

Comment: Your take on Unsung Hero pretty much sums up why I started answering questions on SO. I like answering questions, helping people, and it also improves myself as I get to solve problems daily. Not to mention that it's the only gold I have so far. Thanks for this!

Comment: Lack of upvotes does not merely mean that you haven't helped other people, it means that no one who saw your answer thought positively of it.

Answer (score 10):

Those badges are like military medals.. only you (and people who research your endeavors) know if you deserve the badge.

Some people 'earn' them by posting a truckload of [below mediocre answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166718/is-the-unsung-hero-badge-a-bad-thing). (just like robo-reviewers who are in it only for the badge).

The more intended 'use' of the Unsung Hero badge is 3-fold:
rewarding and motivating experts

- to (continue) to answer 'obscure'/'non-mainstream'/'interesting'/'hard' questions/tags
- who help the new users on the site
- that themselves are new users (low rep.) to (continue) their work in the above 2 categories.
  A way to help those users over the first gap (of 'disappointment') after (say for example) posting 50 quality answers but hardly getting any rep from it (compared to what you would have gotten >3 years ago), by saying: 'your work didn't go un-noticed, we *do* appreciate it'.

I earned the badge whilst being in the third category in the javascript area, where it is hard to earn rep these day's (especially given the audience, fastest-gun-'problem' and ever-growing truckload of library-related questions). And it *did* help me over the gap and I'm proud of (actually earning) it.

I remember (some) similar questions/answers on meta.stackexchange.com from a couple of years ago:

Quote from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/78112):

> It's to reward those people who's answers are accepted but not
>   upvoted. This can be for many reasons - one being that new users can
>   post questions and accept answers, but can't up-vote until they get 15
>   rep, another being where there are few users who are knowledgeable in
>   a tag.
>
> So it's a way of rewarding those people who help the new users to the
>   site.

And [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56723):

> The concept here is to give these "poor users" that participate in
>   tags that are not wildly followed or upvoted or happen to answer less
>   popular questions some extra incentive to keep on making Stack
>   Overflow better.

and:

> its about giving these users that contribute in a less popular way an
>   incentive to keep contributing

In conclusion, assuming you rightfully earned the Unsung Hero badge, then wear it with pride!

Answer (score 8):

No, one should not avoid getting this badge, even more, you cannot if you are dealing with one-rep people and no high-reps to repeatedly upvote your answers. Just take it and don't be shy.

Comment: Right. Another point.  Sometimes you get these **if you and the OP are the only person who even understand what the hell the topic is about**.  ie, you sometimes get one for very obscure, highly technical answers.

Answer (score 3):

How very dare you sir, that was my first gold badge! **grin**

Based on my own barely acknowledged answers, I'd say they were low **value** questions. I've lost count of the questions I've answered with titles like "How do I do this", or "I want the sum of my oojahs to include the one above".

I see it, answer it correctly (ish). The OP thinks cheers, tries it, tells me I've spelled one of their column names wrong, I fix that, they try again, it works, they tick it. I get a wee message and then some time later a gold badge which I didn't even know existed until it magically appeared against my name.

So I'd say a good deal of it is down to low value questions. That's both in terms of applicability unless you are capable of adapting an answer to a similar question and it's tagged and titled well enough to actually be found.

Answer (score 3):

When I actively joined the community in the past, many of my accepted answers initially were zero score and I earned the "unsung hero" badge after some time. However over time many of these answers have been upvoted multiple times, probably by other readers.

Hence I think the badge may reflect the new, active member with many answers too recent to be upvoted. I do not this it could be low quality answers as they are now upvoted as any others.

Answer (score -13):

It depends on what is your goal on this site.
If whatever "progress" - then no doubt go for this badge. Make a pride of it and boast to your friends.

Comment: I assume that even your sight attracts downvotes as many out there feel a _void_ looking at your alias.  Consider changing it; it might pacify many (maybe they'll _feel the void_ less often).

Comment: Huh? Why should I be concerned in pacifying anyone? You've mistaken me with The Pope I guess.