# Why did I not get the unsung hero badge?

Tags: support, badges

I don't claim to be a hero, but according to its definition and from [this Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=2516301) I should have earned the "Unsung Hero" badge, since I have 11 zero-scored accepted answers (more than 10), which are 45% of my total accepted answers (more than 25%). It has been a week since I have fulfilled these requirements.

Comment: I believe the time is 10 days, so you have a couple more days to go.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. I guessed it would take a couple of days max.

Comment: Only accepted answers *at least 10 days old* qualify.

Comment: See more [How long do Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges take to be awarded?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57696/how-long-do-tenacious-and-unsung-hero-badges-take-to-be-awarded)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks for pointing that out. Maybe it should be stated in the description of the badge then, or in the tool that I mentioned in my OP. My question is answered.

Comment: The answer's query doesn't work anymore. Updated is here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your answers must be [**at least 10 days old**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57834) to qualify. Until today you had only 10 such answers; number 11 crosses the threshold in a few hours.

I've [updated the query you found](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i), and [running it against your account](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=2516301) shows that *as of tomorrow* you should qualify for the badge as it still only found 10 qualifying answers today.

Comment: Unless the meta effect leads to upvotes on those answers. :)

Comment: @Wooble I thought about it after posting the question! Please don't upvote my zero-score accepted answers until tomorrow :)

Comment: @vefthym: the last answer 'vests' in 20 minutes. Badges are handed out in batches, hopefully you don't have to wait too long after that. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is not so important actually :) Maybe it is an indication of low-quality answers (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256155/does-getting-unsung-hero-gold-badge-mean-that-you-post-low-quality-answers?rq=1). Certainly, it is not as important as your 5 Billion badges, or being a ninja :)

Comment: @vefthym: ah, but I'll never have a Tenacious or Unsung Hero badge! My next 1000 accepted answers would have to be left at 0 for me to have a shot at Tenacious.. That, or 800 accepted answers would have to be voted *down* to 0..

Comment: @vefthym: congrats on receiving the Unsung Hero badge! :-)

Comment: still I did not awarded for this badge, even I fulfill the match criteria for this badge, can u please check this - http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=1156018

Comment: @rajeshpanchal: You don't match the criteria, you need eleven qualifying answers, the query shows you have 10.

Comment: That doesnt work anymore try https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese: there is zero difference between that query and mine. `count(a.id)` and `count(a.score)` give you the exact same count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters your query was a chat item yesterday in the python chat room. this shows i have only 3 so far, even now, but i earned my unsung yesterday. here it is https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=13062813 . this shows a wrong data for 10 days, even now, but i earned the badge yesterday

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese: That's because the SEDE database is not live, it is updated once a week, on Sunday.

Comment: @MartijnPieters then why does my work?