# Why don't I have the Unsung Hero badge?

Tags: support, badges

I just noticed I *think* I should have the `Unsung Hero` badge. Based on my own counts and [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=2288578) I should have the badge. Can anyone show me why I don't have it?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: @zondo lol I'm pretty sure it's not caching, unless I've only met the requirements in the last hour or so. Badges take about 5 minutes to appear once meeting the requirements in my experience.

Comment: That depends on the badge. Some of them are updated only once a day, I think.

Comment: @zondo Oh really? Interesting. Even so I'm fairly sure if I have indeed met the requirements, I've met them for at least a day already.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I looked at that one, pretty sure my answers are >10 days old.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Why 9 hours? Do you know something I don't? :P

Comment: @Clonkex "shouldiblamecaching" is a joke/satire site, if you haven't caught on to it yet...

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yes I realised that haha :P I'm assuming zondo was using it to suggest I should consider caching as a culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the updated/correct query from the [duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256751/584192),

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197953/how-unsung-am-i?UserId=2288578

It seems that you are two answers short (you have nine, when you need **more than** ten).

[image]

Comment: How strange. I assumed the original query was taking into account creation date because it said I had 11 unvoted accepted answers. I distinctly remember manually counting 13 on my user page, and 2 were too new to be counted, so it matched the query. Why would 2 of my unvoted answers not count?

Comment: No, the query you ran did not check for post creation date. If you refer to the duplicate question, the OP also ran the incorrect version of the query (#7521).

Comment: Yeah I know that now, but I have 13 accepted unvoted answers. The updated query showed 9. 2 of them are too new to be counted. That leaves 2 unaccounted for.

Comment: OH well I'm just dumb, my very first two accepted answers are answers on my own questions. That explains it. Guess I just wait and hope no one upvotes my most recent answers :P

Comment: I got it! I am officially an Unsung Hero! :D

Comment: That doesnt work anymore. try https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1228150/how-unsung-am-i-fixed-ver-includes